# python multiprocessing on windows seems to break out of venv

Tags: windows, python-multiprocessing, python-3.7

I build a python3 application on windows that relies on wheel entry_points because they are an easy way to get executable .exe files. I use venv (the built-in virtual environment module in python3). I was trying to locate another entry point excutalbe relative to my own `sys.prefix`. This went well until I moved the code into a multiprocessing.Process to achieve parallelism. Then I could no longer find my entry point. It turns out, the the mp.Process is not spawned with the venv interpreter. Here is code to reproduce the issue:

```
import multiprocessing, sys

def run():
    print("worker exe:",sys.executable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("main exe:",sys.executable)
    multiprocessing.Process(target=run).start()
```

The output I get from this is: (on windows 10)

```
main exe: C:\venv\Scripts\python.exe
worker exe: C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
```

So it appears that the multiprocessing module breaks out of the virtual environment! How can I get the Process to lauch with the venv interpreter? I have tried setting multiprocessing.set_executable without any luck. Could this be a bug in the multiprocessing module?

Comment: It works as expected in 3.6. This is a bug in multiprocessing due to changes that support the virtual-environment launcher (new in 3.7). It won't be fixed until the next release at the earliest (3.7.6 and 3.8.1). You'll have to work around the problem by passing the path as an argument.

Comment: Thanks Eryk. If you could post this as an answer I can mark the question as answered since there is not much else I can do.